# Probability Measures, and inequalities

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let X and Y be random variables defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{S}, \mathcal{P})$.

I have:

(i) $\mathcal{P}(|X+Y| >\epsilon) \leq \mathcal{P}(X>\epsilon/2) + \mathcal{P}(Y>\epsilon/2) $

(ii) $\mathcal{P}(|X| >\epsilon, |Y|> \epsilon)= c$ implies $ \mathcal{P}(|X+Y|>2\epsilon) =c$

(The real problems are more complicated, I'm just trying to simplify the part I am confused. )

I'm getting caught up in combining and breaking a part these probability measures.  I feel like some of these relationships have to do with the triangle inequality.  Could use some help understanding the intuition.

Answer (score 1):

(i) Follows from $\{|X+Y| >\epsilon\} \subset \{|X| >\epsilon  /2\}  \cup \{|Y| >\epsilon /2\} $. (As noted by aleph_two absolute value signs on RHS are necessary).

(ii) $X=-Y=2\epsilon $ is a counterexample.

Comment: @kpr62: Notice that Kavi has inserted absolute value bars around $X$ and $Y$ in (i), which is probably what you meant. In case not: the statement without absolute value bars is false, e.g. $X=Y=-\epsilon$